# Unit testing with - System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext - causes a Null exception

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, integration-testing, weboperationcontext

I need to ask about that I'm working now on a unit test, and I'm trying to make a test on a specific method within a service.

Inside the method, we have this piece of code

`System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["KindOfImportantHeader"];` 
When calling a method I faced a problem with a **null exception because the headers are empty**.

The issue is that I can't change the implementation of the service and the method; which doesn't allow me to make a (Mock) to pass this issue.

***The only change can I perform is just inside the unit test.***

So, How can I pass values to headers from the unit test?

**Unit Test Framework: XUnit**

**Unit Test Target Framework: .NET 4.6.1**

**Service Framework: .NET 4.6.1**

**Thank You All.**

Answer (score 0):

U can create a wrapper around static!

For example :

```
public class IncomingRequstWrapper
  {
      public virtual string KindOfImportantHeader
      {
         get
         {
            return System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["KindOfImportantHeader"]
         }
      }
  }
```

Then you can mock this wrapper.